# Code generator tools for creating UOW and Repository classes for Entity Framework 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, codegen

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with MVC 4 installed along with Entity Framework 4. Is there any development tools to generate repository and uow classes for EF4? There is an EF4 DBContext generator,  but did not see anything else for the dated EF4.

Answer (score 0):

There is a NuGet package I created:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RepositoryGenerator/

This is targeted to EF6 but it should give you a good starting point, it's a lot easier to change a few statements for EF4 compatibility then to create one from scratch. I'm also working on supporting EF4 in the future.